# Small fonts on boot, gets fixed when I open Appearance window

Tags: boot, fonts, ubuntu-mate, appearance

I'm having a strange problem with a fresh installation of Ubuntu MATE 16.04.2

When I boot, the fonts are all strangely small looking and not quite right. This is what it looks like when I first boot.
[image: First boot]

After opening System -> Preferences -> Look and Feel -> Appearance, all the fonts magically fix themselves, as you can see below. 
[image: Fixed fonts]

Note that all I did was open Appearance. I didn't change any settings. Just the act opening the Appearance window fixes the fonts. This problem occurs everytime I boot.

What's causing this and how can I fix it?

I am running Ubuntu MATE 64-bit 16.04.2 on an Asus G501VW Laptop, with official Nvidia drivers. I also installed the proprietary Intel microcode. It's also worth noting that the laptop comes with a 4k screen, but because of the impracticality of 4k on Linux and especially MATE, I decided to run everything on 1920x1080.

Also, I have a dual monitor setup. My second monitor is 1920x1200. I cropped out the second monitor from the screenshots. I'm not sure if it makes a difference but it's worth noting.

Comment: Hmm.. well I think I fixed the issue. I neglected to mention that when I first installed ubuntu, I set the Rendering to "Subpixel smoothing (LCDs)" in order to make the fonts look nice. I think that's what caused everything to get messed up. I fixed it by going to "Details..." then setting Slight hinting, which seems to reset the "Rendering" option. This isn't a solution, just a workaround for now.

However, I still don't know why setting the Rendering to anything causes this problem, so I'm still waiting for an answer.

Comment: A screenshot would be helpful